# Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I keep getting this error. I already went through all the posts related to this error and tried everything to solve this error but still, I don't know why I am getting this error.

Here is the complete error statement:

```
Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
Home: MyNavigator,
}
```

**App.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen'
import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen'
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen'



const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Loading: { screen: LoadingScreen },
    SignIn: { screen: SigninScreen },
    SignUp: { screen: SignupScreen }

  },
  {
    //launcher screen
    initialRouteName: "Loading"
  }
);

//create app container
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Here is HomeScreen.js 
I have changed nothing here, it's just a bare minimum boilerplate code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen  extends React.Component {
render()
{  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you add `HomeScreen` component code?

Comment: Have a look i have added HomeScreen component @MahdiN

Comment: Can you move your `MainNavigator` to another file? it seems to be a bug. hope it works for you